# Sum of Fibonacci Coefficient Power Series

Tags: polynomials, power-series, fibonacci-numbers

I am working on algorithm to count $g(x,n)$, where

\begin{align*}
g(x, n)&=\sum_{i=1}^nf(i).x^i\\
f(i)&=f(i-1)+f(i-2)\\
f(1)&=1,f(2)=1
\end{align*}

I need to compute $g(x,n)$ in logarithmic time. I've tried to change it into matrix exponentiation form, but turns out it didn't work for me. Is there any other way i can solve this problem?

Comment: The size of fibonacci numbers grows exponentially, as in, $\log ~ g(x, n) \approx O(n^k)$ so you cannot calculate the sum in real log time, the output is too big.  But you can use the fact that $$\begin{bmatrix} f(n + 1) & f(n) \\ f(n)  & f(n - 1) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n$$ and maybe some clever application of geometric series to compute the sum in fake log time, but keep in mind that $x^i$ is a different exponential than the matrix exponential so you may need to use jordan forms to combine them.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Noting
$$ f(i)=\frac1{\sqrt 5}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^i-\frac1{\sqrt 5}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^i$$
so one has
\begin{eqnarray}
g(x,n)&=&\frac1{\sqrt 5}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^ix^i-\frac1{\sqrt 5}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^ix^i.
\end{eqnarray}
You can do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can derive a closed formula from starting with $g(x,n)+xg(x,n)$ and then by using the Fibonacci property and some index shifts you get $g(x,n)$ again as well as some simple additional expressions. Solving the equation for $g(x,n)$ should give you

$$g(x,n) = \frac{x(f(1)-f(2))-f(1)+x^nf(n+1)+x^{n+1}f(n)}{1+x-\frac{1}{x}}$$

at last. The most expensive part is the computation of $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ but this can be done in logarithmic time with matrix exponentiation.

Answer (score 0):

The $g(x, n)$ is the first $n$ terms  of generating function of the Fibonacci sequence that is in the following form:
$$
g(x, n)=Series(\frac{x}{1-x-x^2},n)=x+{x}^{2}+2\,{x}^{3}+\cdots + f_n\,x^n
$$
that means, you need to divide $x$ over $1-x-x^2$ polynomial for $n$ times and after that the quotient is your solution. I hope, you find it useful.